# Using ConnectionStrings and custom ConfigSections in the same App.Config

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I have a custom configSection that works as expected. However, when I add a 'connectionStrings' section, I receive error:

```
Configuration system failed to initialize
```

on line:

```
StencilObjects so = ConfigurationManager.GetSection( "stencilObjects" ) as StencilObjects;
```

Here is the config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connection" connectionString="foo"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <configSections>
    <section name="stencilObjects" type="Stencil.Configuration.StencilObjects, Stencil.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>
  <stencilObjects>
    <tableData>
      <table schema="Auth" name="SecurityQuestion" />
    </tableData>
  </stencilObjects>
</configuration>
```

Is there any limitation when using a custom config section? Does this not allow the use of connectionstrings?

Again, when I remove the connectionStrings, the app runs as expected.

Any idea on what is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found a link to back this up yet with an explicit statement, but I've always used `configSections` at the top of the file without any problems.  Try like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="stencilObjects" type="Stencil.Configuration.StencilObjects, Stencil.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connection" connectionString="foo"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <stencilObjects>
    <tableData>
      <table schema="Auth" name="SecurityQuestion" />
    </tableData>
  </stencilObjects>
</configuration>
```

`configSections` definitely doesn't *need* to be just before the section(s) it describes.  `connectionStrings` can be in between.

Answer (score 0):

As David said in his answer, the `configSections` section needs to be at the top of the config file.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/configsections-element-for-configuration#remarks) is a link to back it up from Microsoft:

> If this element is in a configuration file, it must be the first child
> element of the  element.

So you need to switch around the sections so that it is as follows:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="stencilObjects" type="Stencil.Configuration.StencilObjects, Stencil.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connection" connectionString="foo"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <stencilObjects>
    <tableData>
      <table schema="Auth" name="SecurityQuestion" />
    </tableData>
  </stencilObjects>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You can put a comment or edit the answer to add documentation, no need to add another answer with the exact same config, but thanks for the contribution.

Comment: I wanted to add a comment, but don't have enough reputation to comment on answers other than my own.